# Iphone 3G internet disconnects frequently

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an Iphone 3G with ios 4.2.1. I am using internet on my phone using Cellular data turned ON. It works fine for some time, but after then it disconnects and does not work untill i restart my phone. What is the issue.

Comment: Was your problems solved? I'd be helpful to improve this site by providing feedback no matter if an answer worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Some phones do not **re-login to the celluar network** once disconnected. That's why a restart helps.

However, try **"Reset Network Settings"** on the iphone.